# javascript timer doubles the time value each time it resets and reruns

Tags: javascript, css, function, web

i am starting some javascript projects and i found some difficulties with this timer
first issue is that the stop button doesn't work and i tried many code but nothing works
then each time i click on reset instead of going from 1 to 2 to 3 it goes 1 then
2 and 4 then 8 and so on
i tried looking with the interval but the first time it goes right
so i checked the reset function

```
var timer = document.querySelector("#timer");
var start = document.querySelector("#start");
var pause = document.querySelector("#stop");
var stop = document.querySelector("#stop");



var time_stopped = true;
var hours = 0;
var minutes = 0;
var seconds = 0;




function start_timer() {
    if (time_stopped == true){
        time_stopped = false;
        cycle();
    }
    console.log("timer started!");
    pause.style.display = "unset";
}

function stop_timer() {
    if (stop_timer == false) {
        stop_timer = true;

    }
    console.log("time stopped!");
    pause.style.display = "none";



}

function restart_timer() {
    timer.innerHTML = "00 00 00";
    hours = 0;
    minutes = 0;
    seconds = 0;
    time_stopped = true;
    cycle();

}

function cycle() {

    
    if (time_stopped == false) {
        hours = parseInt(hours);
        minutes = parseInt(minutes);
        seconds = parseInt(seconds);

        seconds = seconds + 1;


        if (seconds == 60) {
            minutes += 1;
            seconds = 0;
        }

        if (minutes == 60) {
            hours += 1;
            minutes = 0;
        }



        if (seconds < 10 || seconds == 0) {
            seconds = "0" + seconds;
        }

        if (minutes < 10 || minutes == 0) {
            minutes = "0" + minutes;
        }

        if (hours < 10 || hours == 0) {
            hours = "0" + hours;
        }




        timer.innerHTML = `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
        setInterval(cycle,1000);

    }
}
```

and here's the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>stopwatch (timer)</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div>

    <div id="timer">
        
            00:00:00
        
    </div>
    <ul>
        <button id="start" onclick="start_timer()">start</button>
        <button id="stop" onclick="stop_timer()">stop</button>
        <button id="restart" onclick="restart_timer()">restart</button>
    </ul>
    </div>


    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: FYI setTimeout is not accurate so adding 1 is going to be off after awhile.

Comment: Every time you call cycle you create another interval..... interval1 creates interval2. Interval1 creates interval3, interval2 creates interval4, interval1 creates interval5, interval2 creates interval6, interval3 creates interval7, interval4 creates interval8......

Comment: i deleted them all and still the same issue but what should i use instead setInterval?

Comment: You should only create one interval.... You should not be creating an interval in cycle....

Comment: thanks so much for helping

Answer (score 0):

The function `setInterval` doesn't just setup one timeout event, it sets up a repeating schedule of them.

So, as noted in the comments, every time you call `cycle()` you are creating *an additional* timer schedule, causing them to effectively double every interval.

To fix this you need to change to `setTimeout` instead of set `Interval`, or alternatively call `clearInterval` before you make a new `setInterval` call (or just do neither, as `setInterval` is already doing the repeating for you).  This doc explains all of these functions: https://javascript.info/settimeout-setinterval

Comment: setTimeout is still going to cause issues with how that code is set up. The fix is more than one line. The timer can still multiply if code is paused and restarted

Comment: @R3d_F1lc0n  Thanks. Remember to upvote answers that were helpful.  And if this solved your problem, then mark it as the answer